# Issue with incrementing variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Dim chr As Range
test = 1

For Each chr In ActiveDocument.Range.Characters
Dim firstChar As Word.Range
Set firstChar = Selection.Characters(test)
MsgBox (Selection.Characters(test))
MsgBox (test)
test = test + 1

Next chr
```

This is supposed to select the first character and then later do something with it , and move to the second character, that part isn't happening as the value of "test" is not increasing , and the macro gives an error of :"the requested collection doesn't exist"

Why isn't the value incrementing .

Comment: The value of test is probably never incremented because the error mentioned is before the point where the increment occurs, but you didn't tell us exactly where the error happens.

Comment: I think the error is happening in `Set firstchar = Selection.Characters(test)`

Comment: Is the error "the requested collection doesn't exist" or "The requested member of the collection does not exist"? You are looping over all characters in the document and try to access that same number of characters in the selection. That will lead to an error if you haven't selected the whole document, at which point the selection becomes irrelevant because you can just use the document range.

Comment: yes , That was the error ,, I wasn't selecting the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it works on the `Selection`. If you don't select any text, it will give you the mentioned error. But why overcomplicate it? This code does what you (seem to) want:

```
Dim chr As Range

For Each chr In Selection.Characters

  MsgBox chr.Text

Next chr
```